# how to print numbers in an array while comparing it with a predefined value in Js

Tags: javascript

I have an array of numbers :

```
array = [20, 44, 55, 66, 24, 38, 500];
key = 25.5;
```

I want to basically compare every value in the array with the key and print the numbers starting with the closest number equal to that key.
ex: in the above instance, I want the o/p to look like:

```
newarray =[24,20,38, 44,66,500] // 24 is closest to 25.5, 20 is second closest to 25.5, 38 is thrid closest to 25.5, etc...
```

code:

```
var len = array.length;

array.forEach(function(i){
  if(i === key) {
    return i;
}

})
```

I'm not sure how to print these numbers based on the closest number in the array.any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Array.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

```js
var array = [20, 44, 55, 66, 24, 38, 500];
var key = 25.5;

array.sort((a, b) => {
  if (Math.abs(a - key) < Math.abs(b - key)) return -1;
  else if (Math.abs(a - key) > Math.abs(b - key)) return 1;
  return 0;
});

console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using a for loop, you'll be better off using Javascript's [`Array.prototype.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) function.

```js
const array = [20, 44, 55, 66, 24, 38, 500];
const key = 25.5;

// Create a sorting helper
sortByClosestToKey = (a, b) => {
  // Calculate how far away each number is from the key
  const aDiff = Math.abs(a - key);
  const bDiff = Math.abs(b - key);
  return (aDiff < bDiff) ? -1 : (aDiff > bDiff) ? 1 : a < b;
}

const sorted = array.sort(sortByClosestToKey);

document.querySelector('#answer').innerText = sorted.toString();
```

```html
<div id="answer"></div>
```